# Resuming an upgrade to 12.04 which got stuck on reconfiguring dropbox

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dropbox

I was upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 and the process got stuck when reconfiguring/downloading dropbox. I had to break the upgrade at 87% and don't think my system will boot now. Is there any way to resume the upgrade in order to complete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe resuming will work. You will need to restart the configuration of all the packages.

During the Grub menu, after you start the PC, select `(recovery mode)`. Then a menu will appear, one of them is about "dpkg" select it and reconfigure all the packages.

If the menu didn't appear, and you went into console mode you can run this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

If if was broken - as it was in my case -, and neither the menu nor the console worked. Then in the Grub choose a "Previous Linux Version" and select any of the Linux Kernel version in `(recovery mode)`. I'd suggest the newest version. And follow the previous two steps.

(Well to be honest I think you can "resume" the upgrade, if you somehow managed to keep track of all the packages that weren't yet configured, by running `dpkg-reconfigure package_name`)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, Dan! I will try that as soon and report the results here.

Comment: Do you also know how to exclude a specific package from installing during such an upgrade? I am afraid that the process will just get stuck again at this dropbox reconfiguration.

Comment: If time isn't an issue, I suggest trying the whole reconfiguration once (It will take quite a while). If it fails, you can always restart it. I cannot say if it was possible or not to exclude a package, as I do not know (I doubt it though). But in any case, you can try removing it with `apt-get remove <package_name>` before doing the configuration.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not quite the question you asked however here is a short discussion about the dropbox problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11891423

In fact to update dropbox it must be stopped (killed via `sudo gnome-system-monitor`)

Comment: Thanks! This was a bit too late for me, but hopefully it'll help others.

Comment: for me - as mentioned above - "sudo killall dropbox" let the upgrade process continue.

Comment: this answer saved my upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Yashima, but, if your system monitor does not show Dropbox, don't be fooled, it's still running in the background. Open up a terminal window and kill it.

Type in "ps -e", scroll and find the Dropbox process, note it's program ID (the number to the left of the name), then type in "kill PID" (replace PID with the program ID of the Dropbox process). If it returns an error, try "sudo kill PID", should work.